# Can the glue of glitter-hot-glue sticks be used to provide evidence of electronics-hardware tampering?

Tags: hardware, physical, detection, protection, tampering

I've been researching low-cost, yet strong, tamper-evident mechanisms, and purchased some low-cost glitter-hot-glue sticks as part of this research. The [Amazon page advertising the sticks](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07RMYCXB2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), seems to indicate (in the product photos) that they can be used on electronics; maybe the photos even hint as to it being possible to use the glue of the sticks, as a tamper-evidence mechanism when the glue is melted over a motherboard jumper (in a similar way to how [glitter nail varnish can be used](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/End-user_Computer_Security/Main_content/Some_measures_that_are_primarily_physical#Applying_glitter_nail_varnish_to_computer_screws) to implement tamper-evidence mechanisms over laptop screws). However, I cannot find on the internet, any other supporting information for using such glue sticks in such ways.

The text in the title is my question.

[image: Photo of glitter hot glue sticks]

Comment: How would the glitter nailpolish work? what is stopping me from replacing the screw and re-applying glitter to it?

Comment: The glitter nail polish idea is not my idea--it appears to have been generally accepted as a viable tamper-evidence mechanism. You need to photograph the nail-varnish patterns; the patterns form something like a "fingerprint". An adversary can remove the paint, and then repaint it, but then the "fingerprint" would change, and that would constitute the tamper evidence.

Comment: The question then becomes if you can recognize the same pattern again. It's possible, but I doubt anyone would go that far in practice. It'll more likely be "The varnish looks fine, so it's probably fine"

Comment: One wonders if the glitter is conductive.  I'd be hesitant to glue over a jumper.

Comment: If you have glitter hot glue on a jumper, all I have to do is heat the other side of the PCB with a hair dryer, then freeze spray (dustoff) the warm glue wad to shatter the mobo bond, then pop the glued jumper off whole, virtually all the glue intact. Re-attach and re-warm to reseal. That, or just short the pins on the back of the jumper (if THT) or downstream of the jumper...